# Partition size from “df -h ” vs “fdsisk -l”

Tags: linux, partitioning, fdisk

Partition size using "df-h"

```
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/sda5        19G   17G  516M  98% /
    none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    udev            285M  4.0K  285M   1% /dev
    tmpfs            57M  432K   57M   1% /run
    none            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
    none            285M     0  285M   0% /run/shm
    none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
    /dev/sda2       4.8G  227M  4.4G   5% /boot
```

Partition size using "fdisk -l /dev/sda2"

```
    Disk /dev/sda2: 20.0 GB, 19999490048 bytes
    161 heads, 2 sectors/track, 121309 cylinders, total 39061504 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0xfa33242a

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sda2p1            2048    25167871    12582912   83  Linux
```

How /dev/sda2 size differ in both cases.?? /dev/sda2 size was initially 20G, i shrinked it to 5G, now i want to move those 15G somewhere else but fdisk still shows /dev/sda2 holding 20G.

Comment: Did you shrink the partition or the volume? Those are potentially different.

Comment: i shrinked partition using "resize2fs /dev/sda2 5G"

Answer (score 0):

From `man resize2fs`:

> The resize2fs program does not manipulate the size of partitions.

...

> If you wish to shrink an ext2 partition, first use resize2fs to shrink the size of filesystem. Then you may use fdisk(8) to shrink the size of the partition. When shrinking the size of the partition, make sure you do not make it smaller than the new size of the ext2 filesystem!